# Drag & drop multiple items of M2M field in Directus

Tags: directus

I have a data model in Directus with Many to Many field called `Games`.
[image]
I know that it is possible to order elements of the M2M field by using drag & drop but I'd like to know if it is possible to drag & drop multiple items at once?

I've tried to look for it in docs but haven't found anything.